# How to inspect memory map on OSX

Tags: macos

The equivalent command for linux is (for the bash process)

```
cat /proc/$$/maps
```

But for my mac, I get this output

```
cat: /proc/501/maps: No such file or directory
```

How to inspect memory map on OSX?

Answer (score 21):

As mentioned, the more correct answer for a memory map resides in `/usr/bin/vmmap`

vmmap will map the memory of a process so be sure to supply a process id as the first arg (`ps aux` for your process selecting pleasure).

ex:
`/usr/bin/vmmap 5555`